# Understanding the Inclusion of "of" and its Impact on Sentence Nuance

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, I'm curious about why the "of" is not omitted in "of the ABO blood groups." Additionally, I'm interested in understanding how the nuance of the sentence would change if "of" were to be omitted. I would appreciate it if you could tell me what it means in grammatical terms.

> A major shift in the approach to physical anthropology occurred at the beginning of the 20th century with the discovery of genetic principles and of the ABO blood groups.

Comment: No reason. No difference.

Comment: It is _included_ to make it clear that 'discovery' refers to both things - two separate discoveries.

Comment: ... Yes, what Kate says. The _distributive singular_ ('discovery of A and of B' = 'discovery of A and discovery of B') rather than using 'discoveries' sounds far more natural, but 'discovery of A and B' sounds like the two were made in the same research project. The expanded form ('discovery of A and discovery of B') is very clunky; I only include it to show meaning.

Comment: Edwin and Kate, now I understood very well. Thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's there to avoid ambiguity.

It sometimes helps to view sentences with comma-separated lists as bullet-pointed lists because it helps you see where the list values would connect back to the leading phrase.

It could read like this:

> A major shift in the approach to physical anthropology occurred at the beginning of the 20th century with the discovery **of**:
>
> - genetic principles
> - ABO blood groups

In which case you'd be right - there's no need for a second 'of' because both list items link back nicely. But, did you notice that there is another preposition in the sentence? '*With*'. So, what if someone read it like this:

> A major shift in the approach to physical anthropology occurred at the beginning of the 20th century **with**:
>
> - the discovery of genetic principles
> - ABO blood groups

Ambiguity. The way it is written avoids it being read this way.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear explanation! I've been bothered by not getting a satisfactory answer from any Generative AI, but now I can feel relieved! English is a very logical language. I am very impressed.